# Proving that a set has a fixed point

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, p-groups

> Let $G$ be a group of order $16$, and $\pi$ a $G$ action on a set $X$, where $|X|=5$.
>
> Prove that $X$ has a fixed point.

I can see that $|X|\not\equiv0$ mod $2$ and I should assume that there is no fixed point and get a contradiction - $|X|\equiv 0$ mod $2$, but now sure how...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Size of orbits divide the order of the group (comes from Orbit-Stabilizer Lemma). So, your orbits should be of size 1, 2, 4, 8, or 16.

The orbit sizes must add up to $|X|$ since the orbits partition the set. Try to add up to 5 using 1, 2, 4, 8, 16. You get only these possibilities: 1+1+1+1+1, 1+1+1+2, 1+2+2, 1+4

So one of the orbits must be size 1, which means it's a fixed point.

See [A question about the fixed point and group action.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/136557/a-question-about-the-fixed-point-and-group-action)

Comment: The size of the set must be the gcd of the orbits sizes?

Comment: But why does it have to sum to $5$?

Comment: Why does it have to sum to the size of the set?